# How to avoid nested function definitions and still use <<- operator

Tags: r, nested, environment

Suppose I have these two functions:

```
fInner<-function()
{
   # Do some complicated stuff, and...
    I<<-I+1
}

fOuter<-function()
{
    I<-0
    fInner()
    print(I)
}
```

Calling `fOuter()` produces an error: `Error in fInner() : object 'I' not found`. I know, that one way of fixing it is to re-write the example into

```
fOuter<-function()
{
    fInner<-function()
    {
        I<<-I+1
    }
    I<-0
    fInner()
    print(I)
}
```

But what if I don't want to nest the functions that way? In my case `fInner` is a very heavy and complicated function (which I might want to move into my library), and `fOuter` is really an ad-hoc created function that defines one iterator. I will have many `fOuter`-class functions in my code, so nesting them will require duplicating the `fInner` inside every single little one iterator definition.

I suspect the solution has something to do with environments, but I don't know how to do it. Can anyone help?

Comment: For some reason I doubt you're going to heed this advice, but it's really probably better to just have `fInner` return the new value of `I`, and then it's available for assignment if needed.

Comment: @joran :-D Well, actually that's a very good answer. I don't know why it didn't come to me at the beginning. But, out of curiosity (not any longer necessity) the question stands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need access to the environment associated with the `fOuter` function--where the call to `fInner` is. You can get this with `parent.frame`, and you can get and set variables with `get` and `assign`:

```
fInner<-function()
{
  assign("I", get("I", envir=parent.frame()) + 1, envir=parent.frame())
}

fOuter<-function()
{
  I<-0
  fInner()
  print(I)
}
```

See `?environment` and `?parent.frame` for more info.

But this is just to satisfy your curiosity! You seem to agree that this is not a good idea. Manipulating environments and names can quickly get complicated, and unless you're doing something truly complex, there's probably a better way.

Comment: That definitely satisfied my curiosity! Thanks